# How to update a app version in the MobileFirst pruduction server 7.0?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-console

It's convenient while developing with the MFP studio (Once any files change, the client will get a update notification which is so-called "direct-update"). But how could make this in a MF production server ?

Do we have to do "Replace project war file" in the MF Server configuration Tool and then the re-select a large version number `.wlapp` file in the `worklightconsole` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike what Srik wrote - you shouldn't carelessly delete the old .wlapp. By doing so, users who use the version of said .wlapp will not longer be able to connect to the server.

So you if need to trigger a direct update, re-deploy the updated .wlapp file when you need to, don't first delete it.

Do not delete it even if deploying a new version (1.1 instead of 1.0).
You should delete only after you are certain that all of the users of 1.0 have migrated to 1.1.

1.1 constitutes of a new version that was also uploaded to the app store.
You can force users to upgrade by "remote disable"ing v1.0 (and point to download the new version). When everyone migrated, you can then delete the old version if you really feel like it.

Deletion is done via MobileFirst Console.

1. Load the console URL
2. Click on Applications

You can delete:

- The entire all with all of its environments:

[image]

- or a specific environment, or a specific version of an environment (if you had for example 1.0 and 1.1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the old .wlapp file and put in your new .wlapp file. There is no need to replace the .war file

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what @Idan Adar wrote, and make some addtion IMO:

1. You are doing iterative development of your app and upgrade your product frequentlyly, but just in UI level and adapter level, you can just update .wlapp files (DO **NOT** delete it ) which will trigger a direct update;
2. I don't think version number in WL console is so important to the end user (they cannot see it and they don't care), so you can just define a version number inside the app then update by direct update;
3. If you changed something big, and changed something platform related ,e.g : in iOS developing you change `worklight.plist` (in this file, which WL server your app is connecting to or WL platformVersion is defined here), then you have to rebuild your app and publish them to App Store or Android market.